# Why am I getting Composer could not find a composer.json file?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I've been using DrupalVM and Gitlab CI. In DrupalVM, there's a folder that's automatically created where all Drupal files reside, along with composer.json and .lock. If I keep my files here, I get a Composer could not find a composer.json file resulted by a composer install. However, I create an additional folder, move all files there and edit my .gitlab-ci.yml to cd  then do a composer install, I'm not getting any errors. Shouldn't I be getting the error if I keep my files above the additional folder and delete the line cd ? What am I doing wrong?

For reference, here's my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
# jobs do not need to be present for all stages, if a stage has no jobs it will just be ignored
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  image: smmccabe/docker:latest
  only:
    - master

  # this tells the build server to save these files between jobs, this keeps them to be deployed
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - drupal

  script:
    # Run Composer to build site (use --no-dev for production builds).
    - cd drupal
    - composer install --no-interaction

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: instrumentisto/rsync-ssh:latest
  only:
    - master

  script:
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan -p $PORT $HOSTNAME >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - stat .gitlabci-rsync-exclude.txt
    - rsync -avz -e "ssh -p $PORT" --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --exclude-from '.gitlabci-rsync-exclude.txt' --delete ./drupal/ $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME:$REMOTE_DOCROOT/$REMOTE_DEPLOY_DIRECTORY_IN_DOCROOT/
    - ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME -p $PORT '/bin/bash -u -e -s' < ./web/scripts/post_deploy.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are `cd` to drupal folder, usually composer file is in the project root folder

```
  script:
    # Run Composer to build site (use --no-dev for production builds).
    - cd drupal # Verify if this folder contain composer.json or not.
    - composer install --no-interaction
```

Please verify if you are in running `composer install` in the correct folder.